# Return value from Coroutine without runBlocking

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Main Activity:

```
btLogin.setOnClickListener {
            hideKeyboard()
            if (etUsername.text.toString().isEmpty() || etPassword.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
                etPasswordInput.error = resources.getString(R.string.main_enter_user_data)
            } else if (viewModel.userLogin(
                    etUsername.text.toString(),
                    etPassword.text.toString(),
                    cbRememberMe.isChecked
                )
            ) {
                //val user: Array<String> = viewModel.getUserLoginData()
                val intent: Intent = Intent(this, ProfilePageActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_USERNAME", "111111")
                intent.putExtra("EXTRA_PASSWORD", "222555")
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }
            else{
                etPasswordInput.error = resources.getString(R.string.main_wrong_username_or_password)
            }
        }
```

MainActivityViewModel:

```
class MainActivityViewModel : ViewModel() {

    fun userLogin(username: String, password: String, remember: Boolean): Boolean {
        return Repository.userLogin(username, password, remember)
    }

    fun getUserLoginData(): Array<String> {
        val array: Array<String> = arrayOf(
            Repository.getStoredUsername(),
            Repository.getStoredPassword()
        )
        return array
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
fun userLogin(username: String, password: String, remember: Boolean): Boolean {
        var response = false
        var responseLogin = ""
        runBlocking {
            job_login = CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
                responseLogin = HUC.httpRequest_Profile(username, password.md5())
                if (responseLogin.contains(loginSuccess)) {
                    if (remember) {
                        preferences.saveUser(
                            username,
                            password,
                            password.md5()
                        )
                    }
                    response = true
                }
            }
            job_login!!.join()
        }
        return response
    }
```

This is how I am trying to implement User Login and it is working properly, BUT, it is blocking my UI thread until HTTP request is finished which results in a freeze right after a button is pressed which is not very good for user experience.

Here is what I am looking to do:

- User pressed a button
- Small progress bar appears meaning that the information is being processed
- Data is sent for processing, meanwhile all animations on UI are finished, keyboard is hidden and etc.
- Response from data processing is then being sent back to MainActivity
- MainActivity is then processing the response and from then it either displays the error message or transfers to UserProfile

This is how I am trying to implement all this and the only thing I am having hard time implement is making it run without UI being blocked, help me understand how to achieve this

I was thinking that the right way to go about this would be a MutableLiveData with a Boolean value that would have a listener on MainActivity and inside a viewModel it would be changed depending on the response value from Repository, but maybe there is some other solution to this that I have not considered

Comment: Have your repository implement a proper `suspend` function. Have your viewmodel emit a viewstate via `LiveData` that contains your login data. Have your activity observe that viewstate and update its UI accordingly. See [this](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/tree/v0.9/Weather) and [this](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-coroutines-rxresult/-/tree/v0.2) and [this](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/-/tree/vFINAL/ConferenceVideos) as examples.

Comment: @CommonsWare Absolutely gorgeous solution. Thank you very much